# \renewcommand or \patchcmd (from etoolbox)?

Tags: koma-script, etoolbox, front-matter

I have seen a number of example that use `\patchcmd` from the [`etoolbox`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package. I am not too familiar with this package and wanted to understand what would be the appropriate situation to use `\patchcmd` instead of `renewcommand`.

My use-case  involves changing the definition of `\maketitle` in the KOMA-Script  package to give me greater control on the individual pages comprising the frontmatter.

Comment: Using `\patchcmd` for the title with a KOMA-class isn't a very good idea, imho. Use `renewcommand` to redefine the title *If you need this more than once*. If you need it just once, don't waste time in patching and redefining, do the page(s) from scratch. Please see [How to customize my titlepage?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/210280)

Comment: @Johannes_B I would have thought it potentially made more sense with KOMA than with standard classes because `\maketitle` does a lot more in e.g. the case of books, for example. But only if patching is appropriate in the first place, of course, and the one-offness is definitely a good point.

Comment: @cfr KOMA has many advantages, it has an interface for almost eery little detail. But every interface is limited. Have a look at the hardcore answers concerning chapter titles that patch (or renew) 7 different little screws that allow the interface to get something done that would be doable (with a bit of func. loss) with a very simple redifinition. On the other hand, the internal code got so complicated, that i cannot find a defintion that i could patch. Try to find the definitiion for `sectionmark` in case you want to patch that.

Comment: @Johannes_B Maybe you should answer. I'm thinking mine may not be very useful and wondering whether I should delete it - it seems perhaps too generic given what you say about KOMA.

Comment: @cfr nah, your answer is fine. The title isn't very complex, even with KOMA. But other stuff can be. :-)

Comment: I am accepting @cfr answer below, primalrily because it pointed out the key aspects of what `\patchcmd` does - I love the analogy to house renovation.

@Johannes_B also pointed out very helpfully the right way to go for the titlepage and pointer to an extremely helpful question on SE. His comments on the intricacies of KOMA-script and the difficulty of finding code to patch is very apt.

Comment: @Johannes_B: In my particular case, i want to make this code re-usbale for others in the university, hence I think i will go with rewriting the `\maketitle` macro. Any pointers on how can I start doing that in the context of KOMA-Script? In http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/210280/42648 you do point out a way to do it with KOMA-script using the `titlepage` package. Any pointers on how to get my own style in `titlepage` or would I be better off starting from scratch?

Comment: Hm, it seems my answer is unclear. That would be the section *How to make a solid titlepage?* It doesn't really matter if you use KOMA or not, the principle is the same.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no hard-and-fast rule. There are cases where `\patchcmd` won't work, but you can always use one of the more sophisticated patching options in that case.

Generally, if you want to design what `\maketitle` does from scratch, use `\renewcommand`; if you want to adjust what `\maketitle` does, use `\patchcmd`.

It is the difference between knocking down a house in order to build a new one and extending or modifying an existing house. There are borderline cases, but if you just want a wooden door rather than a plastic one, modification is the better option; if you want to add a basement swimming pool and turn a 1 room shack into a 3 storey mansion, then rebuilding from scratch makes more sense.

If you would start to build your command by copying the code from KOMA in order to edit it, there's a good chance patching may make sense. If you would start to build your command by just writing code to do something different, patching is unlikely to make much sense.

The real advantage of patching is that you'll benefit from updates to the original. One disadvantage, of course, is that the update may break your patch. But you probably want to know in this case anyway, as other, less obvious, complications may follow.

Problems are easier to track down and identify if good use is made of the final two arguments of `\patchcmd`.

```
\patchcmd{<macro name>}
  {<to be replaced>}
  {<replacement>}
  {\typeout{Patching of <macro name without backslash> succeeded.}}
  {\typeout{Patching of <macro name without backslash> failed.}}
```

This allows you to scrutinise the console output or `.log` file for relevant lines, enabling you to check whether the patch was successful or not. You can also assess the patching process (and success or failure) by adding `\tracingpatches` to your preamble after loading the package.

Comment: @Werner Thanks for editing. I wasn't ignoring your `\tracingpatches` suggestion but I've never used it and was too tired to look it up right away, so thought I'd come back to it.