# how to separate the numbering of different environment in latex?

Tags: numbering

I am using `wiley-article` class. In my text I have examples and definitions. The problem is the numbering of both is mixed. For example, suppose I have the following:

```
\begin{example}
bla bla
\end{example}

\begin{definition}
xo xo
\end{definition}

\begin{example}
    bla2 bla2
    \end{example}
```

The output is:

```
Example 1: bla bla
Definition 2: xo xo
Example 3: bla2 bla2
```

So what I need is to get a specific counter for the examples and another counter for the definition. Thus the output for the example above will be:

```
Example 1: ...
Definition 1 :...
Example 2:...
```

Noting that, the example and definition environments are built in the `wiley-article` class. So, if I add `\usepackage{amsthm}` I get errors since this class  already has its own theorem and example and definition environments.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This might not be particularly helpful for LaTeX, but can you try `\tracingassigns2\tracingonline1` and then put `\show\def` immediately after the `\end{definition}`. What, if any, count changes have been logged?

Answer (score 2):

The solution is so easy. Just the wiley-article.cls
remove from  `[theorem]` from the line

```
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
```

Comment: Rather than directly modifying the `.cls` file (which in general is not a good idea), this is best done with a patch.  `\patchcmd` is provided by `etoolbox`, and [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/325763) provides help on how to use it.